# `git add` doesn't add files to track on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I have a local folder which I wanted to convert to a Git repository and then push to a remote repository. I ran the command `git init` in the project folder and then used the command `git add .`. When I run the command `git status`, I get the message that I have untracked files. I ran the `git add .` command multiple times but I see the same message.

What should I do to track these files so I can push to a remote repo?

I'm using Windows 8.1 x64 machine.

UPDATE: Please see the answer below.

[image]

Comment: What output do you get when you try `git add .`?  Also, are you using msysgit?

Comment: does `git add CHANGELOG.md` change the status?

Comment: I see a lot of warnings such as 'The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/express-beautify/node_modules/js-beautify/node_modules/nopt/node_mo
dules/abbrev/test.js.'

Comment: I was able to add CHANGELOG.md and see as tracked.

Comment: I see an error 'fatal: unable to stat 'node_modules/webpack/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/anymatch/node_modu
les/micromatch/node_modules/braces/node_modules/expand-range/node_modules/fill-range/node_modules/repeat-string/package.
json': Filename too long' It stopped at the error. All other are warnings.

Comment: You should edit that into the question, and also mention which distribution of `git` you installed. (Remember, StackOverflow is not only a place to get answers, but an *archive* of questions and answers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the command **git config --system core.longpaths true** to fix the error for longer file names. I was able to add all files after making that change.